# How to install devstack pointing mitaka milestone1?

Tags: devstack

I try to install the devstack using stack.sh, How to I clone the mitaka milestone1 for the devstack installation

For example
git clone http://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack mitaka it shows error

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack  -b stable/mitaka
```